# Jms MessageListener onMessage creating multiple receivers at Tibco

Tags: jms

I have implemented JMS queue consumer in Spring configurations. This is connecting to tibco JMS queue. I have one class file XYZ which implements MessageListener which receives JMS messages in onMessage method.

But after receiving few messages, number of receivers are building up at Tibco side. Subsequent messages are not received by the onMessage method. I have set the `Jms:listener-container concurrency="1"`.

**Spring configuration**

```
<bean id="tibcoEMSQueueConnector"  class="com.ril.core.tibco.TibcoEMSQueueConnector">    
 </bean>       
 <bean id="tibcoConnectionFactory" class="com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnectionFactory">    
<constructor-arg value="url"/>    
<property name="userName" value="username"/>    
        <property name="userPassword" value="password"/>    
</bean>    
<jms:listener-container concurrency="1" connection-factory="tibcoConnectionFactory" destination-type="queue">    
        <jms:listener destination="receiverQueueName" ref="tibcoEMSQueueConnector    
    </jms:listener-container>
```

**Sample listener**

```
public class TibcoEMSQueueConnector implements MessageListener    
{    
    @Override
    public void onMessage(final Message message)    
    {     
        if (message instanceof TextMessage)    
        {    
            final TextMessage tm = (TextMessage) message;    
            System.out.println(tm.getText());    
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question, it seems not to be finished: "I have set the ...". Also insert some minimal code example with error, see: [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have corrected the  formatting and added code samples as well.